# SQL: How do I find records that are within X days of one another?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a database called `employees` which looks like this:

```
employee_id   department   hire_date
1             Auto         2000-01-05
2             Auto         2000-01-06
3             Sports       2000-01-06
4             Auto         2000-01-10 
5             Toys         2000-02-20
6             Tools        2000-02-22
7             Toys         2000-02-23
```

**I want to return the employees that were hired within 2 days of one another.**

Here's the closest that I've been able to get:

```
SELECT 
e1.employee_id, e1.hire_date, e1.department, 
e2.employee_id, e2.hire_date, e2.department
FROM employees AS e1
JOIN employees AS e2 ON e1.department = e2.department
WHERE e2.hire_date = e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

The code above gives me the employees that were hired within 2 days of on another but only for their respective departments. Meaning, that it will return employees 1 and 2 (Auto) instead of employees 1, 2 & 3 (Auto & Sports). I'm assuming this is because I did a self-join using the common `department` column.

**I can't figure out how to return the list of employees that were hired within 2 days of one another, regardless of department.**

**Edit:** The following code also does not work as it is only returning the hire dates less than 2 days in the same department, not across all departments:

```
SELECT 
e1.employee_id, e1.hire_date, e1.department, 
e2.employee_id, e2.hire_date, e2.department
FROM employees AS e1
JOIN employees AS e2 ON e1.department = e2.department
WHERE e2.hire_date BETWEEN e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '1 days' 
AND e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

**Edit 2:** Both answers provided by @dzhukov and @Bohemian work. See my comments under their answers for the final result for my actual dataset.

Comment: Which DBMS is the query for?

Comment: I'm using Postgres but this code should work for MySQL as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to restrict the join to department, why do you have that as a join criteria?

Also, you are only returning rows that have *exactly* 2 days difference:

```
WHERE e2.hire_date = e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

but you need to include everything between the same date and 2 days out:

```
WHERE e2.hire_date between e1.hire_date and e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '2 days'
AND e2.employee_id != e1.employee_id
```

The added condition on employee_id prevents rows from joining to themselves.

Replace the join condition on department with the above condition:

```
SELECT
...
FROM employees AS e1
JOIN employees AS e2 ON e2.employee_id != e1.employee_id
  AND e2.hire_date between e1.hire_date and e1.hire_date + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

Comment: That's a good catch but unfortunately that does not fix the problem. I am, of course, using a simpler database in the example above. In my actual database, the code doesn't work.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher see improved answer that uses vanilla (portable) SQL.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher if you’re using a simpler, contrived example in your question you should be absolutely certain that any issues you’re encountering with answers that “don’t work” are because of bugs in the answer and not in a failure to translate the advice back into your more complex scenario.

Comment: The reason I had used the department column to join was that when I had used employee_id, it didn't work. Looking at your code, I had no idea that I could join using negation. I think your edited code works but the only issue is that it repeats some rows https://i.imgur.com/ct2sTPR.png

Comment: @CaiusJard I made a small mistake but that doesn't change the fundamental problem with the query.

Comment: @bohemian minor note about portability of sql- the provided example doesn’t run on MySQL without modification because MySQL doesn’t like apostrophes round interval specs (and PG does), AFAIAA..

Comment: @Iam you can join on anything you like, even stuff that doesn’t make sense like `a JOIN b ON day(now()) = ‘Tuesday’` (pseudocode) if you want a query that produces a Cartesian explosion once a week :) - in terms of “what happens during a join” consider that “every row is joined to every other row, and then only those rows for which the ON is true are kept”

Comment: @Bohemian I got your code to work. I used UNION to move the records into 1 column, which also removes the duplicates. https://i.imgur.com/6zekXHe.png Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is could be solution for MS-SQL, using LAG function.
Does it work for you?

```
declare
    @t table (employee_id int, department varchar (10), hire_date date)

insert into @t
values

(1,             'Auto',         '2000-01-05')
,(2,             'Auto',         '2000-01-06')
,(3,             'Sports',       '2000-01-06')
,(4,             'Auto',         '2000-01-10')
,(5,             'Toys',         '2000-02-20')
,(6,             'Tools',        '2000-02-22')
,(7,             'Toys',         '2000-02-23')


select 
employee_id
,department
, hire_date
from (
SELECT 
LAG(hire_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY employee_id ) prev_hire_date
,*
FROM @t  AS e1
)t

where datediff(dd, prev_hire_date, hire_date) <=2
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: Couple of minor notes (for other/future readers); LAG is only available in MySQL 8+, though PG has had it for much longer. And DATEDIFF in MSSQL is a bit quirky in that at it counts the number of times the requested interval changes between two dates; if the dates have times then an employee hired at 2020-01-01 00:00:00 and one hired at 2020-01-01 23:59:59 will report as being in the 2 day window even though it’s pretty much 3 days. To resolve this we can use more precise intervals (eg get hours between the dates and ask for `<=48`) or cast to date (in this case because it’s days)

Comment: ps: *does it work for you* - well, we.. no it won’t because SQLS date handling is typically different to PG and the latter lacks a DATEDIFF function but http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff Has some useful tips on sqls vs pg date diffing

Comment: @dzhukov Thanks for your patience. I had to convert the syntax for Postgres. The following works: 

`SELECT q1.employee_id, q1.hire_date, q1.prev_id, q1.prev_hire_date

FROM

(
SELECT *, 
LAG(hire_date, 1) OVER(ORDER BY hire_date ASC) AS prev_hire_date,
LAG(employee_id, 1) OVER(ORDER BY hire_date ASC) AS prev_id
FROM employees
) AS q1

WHERE (q1.hire_date::date - q1.prev_hire_date::date) <= 2

ORDER BY q1.hire_date`

https://i.imgur.com/VYNmqvR.png